# Reset width from child element when parent is 100%?

Tags: html, css

I'm using foundation as a basic template for my Website. Now i have a span-element inside many divs.

**The parent element is a div with width: 100%,** what i need, but the span has text now, with a background color.

> So i just want the span-width adjusting by the text, and not by the
>   parent element. How to do this?

`width: initial or auto` is not working.

EDIT:

CSS looks like:

```
span.error, small.error {
  background: #B86566;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.375rem 0.375rem;
  text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-if="method_here" class="error">
<span class="arrow_up"></span>
  {{validation_message}}
</span>
```

All of this is inside an div which has a width: 100%.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: span is a inline element. Set width won't make any effect on inline element. Have you add diplay block on span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the span to `display: inline-block;`.